# Maintenance Window Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know what window CosmosDB uses for system updates?  Is there any impact to users during this updates.  I've been combing through the documents to find the answer to this but they're pretty vague at least with what I've found.  Also we know there is a default window on Sunday at like 4am EST and we know it can be customized for other services.

Thanks.

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic here, as it's about the actual service policy, SLA, etc. and not specific to programming. Also, as mentioned in Marks' answer, there's no advertised maintenance windows, as Azure's *as-a-service* offerings don't expose such a thing to end-users, and this is just something you don't have to worry about (again, I would suggest reading up on service SLAs, for uptime details).

Comment: Thank you very much David.  Yeah was trying to find an answer for someone and this provided the answer I was looking for.  Thank you and sorry for being in the wrong topic for this.

Answer (score 1):

The dates and times for updates within the Cosmos DB service is not published. Service updates have no impact on service availability. As Cosmos DB is a multi-tenant service, this is not something that can (or needs) to be customized.